# Accessing a session in jQuery

Tags: jquery, session

Can I set a session variable in jQuery?

I need to store some data in the session from jQuery and I also want to retrieve that data via jQuery.

Is there anything like

```
$.getSession.set("var","value");
```

Comment: The session you're thinking of sounds to be the server session, often accessed with things like $_SESSION in PHP, and the only way to access that is on the serverside, but you could use ajax to set and get values. There's also a built in session storage in modern browsers called sessionStorage, and works just like localStorage, only it's emptied when the session ends.

Comment: Server Session **can contain highly sensitive data**. Do not blindly publish its content on the client side! What requirement could justify to access sessions variable from client side? I'm quite sure there are better way. Can you describe your actual requirement?

Comment: @Steve B: as you've just said, it **can contain**. Basically it's just a honest container you can store anything you want inside. The suitability of such approach is another case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session is accessible at the server side. But if you want, you can access your session by writing a function, which for example invokes ajax request to your server and gets whatever you want.

**EDIT:**

I'll show you this using ASP.NET MVC framework, as I like it much. For the other frameworks idea is the same - just ask server about session.

So, let it be like below at the server side - simple controller and 2 basic actions are written:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        // store sample data
        Session["user"] = new { name = "Anton Chigurh", age = 42 };
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetSessionValue(string key)
    {
        return Json(Session[key]);
    }        
}
```

Firstly, you have to store something into the session, for example by invoking `Index` action. Next, invoke the `GetSessionValue` action to retrieve value previously stored. Unless you have disabled session for your application, or cookies in your browser, you should get correct value.

How to get the value ? Just send ajax request:

1. You can write javascript function which will do synchronous request - which in fact can freeze your browser for some minor time (depends on your server time consumption used for some calculations, network infrastructure conditions etc.):

   ```
   function getSessionValue(key) {
       var result;
       $.ajax({
           url: "/Home/GetSessionValue",
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: JSON.stringify({ key: key }),
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           async: false
       }).done(function (data) {
           result = data;
       });
       return result;
   }

   // invoke
   var user = getSessionValue("user");
   console.log(user.name + ": " + user.age);
   ```
2. or an asynchronous version, which invokes a callback when done:

   ```
   function getSessionValue(key, callback) {    
       $.ajax({
           url: "/Home/GetSessionValue",
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: JSON.stringify({ key: key }),
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',        
       }).done(function (data) {
           callback(data);
       });
   }

   // invoke 
   getSessionValue("user", function(x) {
       console.log(x.name + ": " + x.age);
   });
   ```

BTW: I've used json seriazlization, as it's the approach I prefer while passing the objects to and from the server. Other thing - jQuery `done` event will only be triggered on success. In case of some errors at the server side (ex: uncaught exception), request returns http 500 and event is not invoked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.Can you provide me an example for accessing session using ajax call in Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at handling client-side sessions with jQuery, you would need a plugin for that.

One that I can think of is [jQuery Session Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin).

Comment: Hi I tried this.
It is OK with storing and Retriving Strings,but not able to store objects returned from ajax call.